# JIRA Query to compute the dat of the latest status

Tags: jira, jql

I would like to ask if there's a way to get only the latest status in doing bucketing the age of tickets?

Scenario is status is:  "Open" - "Ongoing" - "Review" **3 days ago**

However, the ticket went back from "Review" - "Ongoing" 2 days ago.

And now, the ticket just came in (today) as "Review" but i'm still getting the ticket under the age bucket of "3 days" since the ticket went to Review status 3 days ago.

Query is something like this =

```
status changed to "Review" before -3d
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this :
**(status changed to "Review" before -3d) and !(status changed to "Review" after -3d)**

This will give you the list of issue that was changed to Review before (-3d). And excluding the issues that were changed to Review after the same date.